why get different accuracy every time run program
I train a model with keras tensorflow in python.
Also as you can see in the below code, I used seed parameter, but every time I run same code with same data, I face with different accuracy percentage.
My code:
#Seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
set_random_seed(42)
random.seed(42)

data = ('data.csv')

data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['cp', 'restecg'], drop_first=True)

X = data.drop('num', axis=1)
y = data['num']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

def create_model(optimizer='adam', init='glorot_uniform', neurons=[16, 8], dropout_rate=0.3):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Dense(neurons[0], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(neurons[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

param_grid = {
    'optimizer': ['adam', 'rmsprop'],
    'model__neurons': [[16, 8]],
    'model__init': ['glorot_uniform', 'normal'],
    'model__dropout_rate': [0.3],
    'epochs': [50], 
    'batch_size': [10],
}

model = KerasClassifier(model=create_model, verbose=0)

kfold = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=kfold, n_jobs=-1)
grid_search_result = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(f"Best Parameters: {grid_search_result.best_params_}")
print(f"Best Accuracy: {grid_search_result.best_score_}")

best_model = grid_search_result.best_estimator_

keras_model = best_model.model
keras_model.trainable = False 

y_pred_prob = best_model.predict(X_test).flatten()
y_pred = np.where(y_pred_prob > 0.5, 1, 0)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_prob)

print(f'Accuracy (manual calculation): {accuracy:.2f}')
print(f'ROC AUC: {roc_auc:.2f}')

I need to get same accuracy every time.
How should i solve this problem?

If you are using GPU(s) for training, some calculations can be non-deterministic on them. This usually only results in very small differences in the final scores, so if you just see some "noise" on it, then it could be a problem.
You can force TF to be as deterministic as possible using: tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
This might make your training a bit slower, but hopefully more deterministic.
You could also try a few very short trainings using CPU (which should be fully deterministic, if you seeded everything correctly), just to check if your seeding is OK.

Thanks i used it and worked. Thank you
